# Обособление оборота (2)

Tags: причастный-оборот

> Гражданка Украины, с просроченным на 25 лет паспортом...

Обособляется ли причастный оборот?

Answer (score 2):

Это **не причастный оборот,** а оборот на основе падежной формы существительного "с паспортом" (причастие входит в эту форму в качестве определения).

Обособление оборота **зависит от текста**. Скорее всего, оборот имеет значение  **определения** для  существительного "гражданка" (**а не уточнения**) и  поэтому  не обособляется, например:

Вопрос для консультации у юриста: **Гражданин Украины с просроченным паспортом** (с мая месяца, 2014 года),  находящийся в России, ...как выехать в Украину?

Вариант с обособлением: Гражданка Украины из лагеря беженцев, с просроченным на 25 лет паспортом....  Здесь оборот будет иметь уточняющее значение.

Answer (score 0):

Резюмируя: не п/о и не требует обособления.